# Extract the data in the string as column values with some header

Tags: python-3.x

I have log files as shown below

GET /Membership_ID/1891/09/14/week HTTP/1.1" 200 5118 84.201.133.5 "-" "Mozill
GET /Membership_ID/1993/03/19 HTTP/1.1" 200 4976 93.158.161.6 "-" "Mozilla/5.0
GET /Membership_ID/1034/7/17 HTTP/1.1" 200 5054 84.201.133.5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 
GET /Membership_ID/1432/11/09 HTTP/1.1" 200 5041 93.158.161.6 "-" "Mozilla/5.0
GET /Membership_ID/1321/04 HTTP/1.1" 200 5014 84.201.133.5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (c
GET /Membership_ID/1046/06/01 HTTP/1.1" 200 4950 93.158.161.6 "-" "Mozilla/5.0
GET /Membership_ID/1512/08/12 HTTP/1.1" 200 5040 84.201.133.5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0
GET /Membership_ID/1914/03/07 HTTP/1.1" 200 5033 93.158.161.6 "-" "Mozilla/5.0
GET /Membership_ID/1411/12/24 HTTP/1.1" 200 4965 84.201.133.5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0
GET /Membership_ID/1440/4 HTTP/1.1" 200 5008 93.158.161.6 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (co
GET /Membership_ID/1356/04/27 HTTP/1.1" 200 5031 84.201.133.5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0
GET /Membership_ID/1343/11/23 HTTP/1.1" 200 5046 93.158.161.6 "-" "Mozilla/5.0
GET /Membership_ID/1514/06/03 HTTP/1.1" 200 5024 84.201.133.5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0
GET /Membership_ID/1152/08/30 HTTP/1.1" 200 5049 93.158.161.6 "-" "Mozilla/5.0
GET /Membership_ID/1447/3/29 HTTP/1.1" 200 5043 84.201.133.5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 
GET /Membership_ID/1047/11/9 HTTP/1.1" 200 5032 93.158.161.6 "-" "Mozilla/5.0

I need to use Python to get the membership_ID as column name and the number after it as column value. For each unique membership_id entry a counter should be updated

Comment: `import re,pandas as pd;  pd.DataFrame({membership_ID: re.findall(r'(?m)(?<=Membership_ID.)(\d+)',file.read())})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty using Pandas:

```
import pandas
rawLogs=[];splitLogs=[];
rawLogs.append('GET /Membership_ID/1993/03/19 HTTP/1.1" 200 4976 93.158.161.6 "-" "Mozilla/5.0')
rawLogs.append('GET /Membership_ID/1994/03/19 HTTP/1.1" 200 4976 93.158.161.6 "-" "Mozilla/5.0')
rawLogs.append('GET /Membership_ID/1993/03/19 HTTP/1.1" 200 4976 93.158.161.6 "-" "Mozilla/5.0')

for log in rawLogs:
    splitLogs.append(log.split('/'))

dfLogs=pandas.DataFrame(splitLogs)
dfResult=dfLogs.groupby([2]).count()
print(dfResult)
```